# ShrinkToFit does not expand frozen columns if grid has width to expand

Tags: jqgrid

I'm creating a pivot table using jqgrid with group headers. I do some calculation on input data to figure out if combined column width would exceed the fixed width of grid. If it does not exceed then i would change `shrinkToFit : true`for grid to occupy full width. If I do it, then dragging column width creates alignment issues between header and body.

Problem gets worse if frozen column are enabled. The fixed header div wont expand like the column underneath it if `shrinkToFit` is enabled.

Here is a demo to understand the problem :  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NbxWrQ

Any leads will be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try the same code with [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.5 instead of retro version 4.6: http://codepen.io/OlegKi/pen/xRZwmj